# Why don't use inheritance to write C++ standard library but different containers use their own member functions?

Tags: c++

Many member functions of containers in the standard library are the same. Why don't use inheritance to write C++ the standard library but different containers use their own member functions?
Such as: begin, end push_back and so on.

[Containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: Are you aware of the differences between templated classes and runtime polymorphism?

Comment: having same interface does not require runtime polymorphism. Your "but" is no "but".

Comment: what advantage do you expect from using inheritance?